# How can I filer JSON data with multiple objects in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have JSON data array of

```
[
  {
    _id: 5f2084f656dc2428e96fbe92,
    category: [ '5e5150c6c52a3904b74d6ff7', null ],
    coordinates: { lat: 37.8025909, lng: -122.4336412 },
    location: { type: 'Point', coordinates: [Array] },
    calcDistance: 3323.833296768243
  },
  {
    _id: 5f2084fb56dc2428e9703f3b,
    category: [ '5e5150bcc52a3904b74d6ff6', null ],
    coordinates: { lat: 37.7683708, lng: -122.4564649 },
    location: { type: 'Point', coordinates: [Array] },
    calcDistance: 3340.838606150309
  },
  {
    _id: 5f2084f656dc2428e96fbe86,
    category: [ '5e5150c6c52a3904b74d6ff7', null ],
    coordinates: { lat: 37.7669182, lng: -122.4561008 },
    location: { type: 'Point', coordinates: [Array] },
    calcDistance: 3349.000719541262
  },
  {
    _id: 5f2084fb56dc2428e9703f3f,
    category: [ '5e5150bcc52a3904b74d6ff6', null ],
    coordinates: { lat: 37.7669182, lng: -122.4561008 },
    location: { type: 'Point', coordinates: [Array] },
    calcDistance: 3349.000719541262
  },
  {
    _id: 5f2084fa56dc2428e9702130,
    category: [ '5e5150bcc52a3904b74d6ff6', null ],
    coordinates: { lat: 37.7669182, lng: -122.4561008 },
    location: { type: 'Point', coordinates: [Array] },
    calcDistance: 3349.000719541262
  },
  {
    _id: 5f2084fb56dc2428e9703ee5,
    category: [ '5e5150bcc52a3904b74d6ff6', null ],
    coordinates: { lat: 37.7787325, lng: -122.4572683 },
    location: { type: 'Point', coordinates: [Array] },
    calcDistance: 3357.3418413767595
  },
  {
    _id: 5f2084f856dc2428e96ff091,
    category: [ '5e5150bcc52a3904b74d6ff6', null ],
    coordinates: { lat: 37.8049528, lng: -122.4249378 },
    location: { type: 'Point', coordinates: [Array] },
    calcDistance: 3377.281713590449
  },
  {
    _id: 5f2084fb56dc2428e9703f73,
    category: [ '5e5150bcc52a3904b74d6ff6', null ],
    coordinates: { lat: 37.8049528, lng: -122.4249378 },
    location: { type: 'Point', coordinates: [Array] },
    calcDistance: 3377.281713590449
  },
  {
    _id: 5f2084fb56dc2428e9703f39,
    category: [ '5e5150bcc52a3904b74d6ff6', null ],
    coordinates: { lat: 37.7788351, lng: -122.4575644 },
    location: { type: 'Point', coordinates: [Array] },
    calcDistance: 3384.6341862170793
  },
  {
    _id: 5f14aa92745456119cf27701,
    category: [ '5e5150f0c52a3904b74d6ffb', null ],
    coordinates: { lat: 37.779187, lng: -122.4577491 },
    location: { type: 'Point', coordinates: [Array] },
    calcDistance: 3405.9730381738473
  },
  {
    _id: 5f2084fb56dc2428e9703f21,
    category: [ '5e5150bcc52a3904b74d6ff6', null ],
    coordinates: { lat: 37.8034776, lng: -122.4027084 },
    location: { type: 'Point', coordinates: [Array] },
    calcDistance: 3501.3565554464535
  },
]
```

I want to find an object that has a category on of 'favTypes' that returns

```
"5e5150bcc52a3904b74d6ff6,5e5150c6c52a3904b74d6ff7,5e5150d6c52a3904b74d6ff8"
```

Searching objects that have one of this three object_Id in their category. I have tried

```js
jsondatas.filter(jsondata => word.category = favTypes);
```

However, it is returning the jsondatas not filtered objects. Is there any way that I can filter

Comment: Filter will return the object(json) which satisfies the match condition. What do you need exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.indexOf() on each iterating as array or the whole as a string indexOf(), .includes() or .match()

Answer (score 0):

You have to use "==" instead of "=".

"jsondatas.filter(jsondata => word.category == favTypes)"

Answer (score 0):

You can use nested foreach and add some condition, then push it to the initial array. See the code below

```js
const arr = [
  {
    _id: "5f2084f656dc2428e96fbe92",
    category: ["5e5150c6c52a3904b74d6ff7", null],
    coordinates: { lat: 37.8025909, lng: -122.4336412 },
    location: { type: "Point", coordinates: [Array] },
    calcDistance: 3323.833296768243,
  },
  {
    _id: "5f2084fb56dc2428e9703f3b",
    category: ["5e5150bcc52a3904b74d6ff6", null],
    coordinates: { lat: 37.7683708, lng: -122.4564649 },
    location: { type: "Point", coordinates: [Array] },
    calcDistance: 3340.838606150309,
  },
  {
    _id: "5f2084f656dc2428e96fbe86",
    category: ["5e5150c6c52a3904b74d6ff7", null],
    coordinates: { lat: 37.7669182, lng: -122.4561008 },
    location: { type: "Point", coordinates: [Array] },
    calcDistance: 3349.000719541262,
  },
  {
    _id: "5f2084fb56dc2428e9703f3f",
    category: ["5e5150bcc52a3904b74d6ff6", null],
    coordinates: { lat: 37.7669182, lng: -122.4561008 },
    location: { type: "Point", coordinates: [Array] },
    calcDistance: 3349.000719541262,
  },
  {
    _id: "5f2084fa56dc2428e9702130",
    category: ["5e5150bcc52a3904b74d6ff6", null],
    coordinates: { lat: 37.7669182, lng: -122.4561008 },
    location: { type: "Point", coordinates: [Array] },
    calcDistance: 3349.000719541262,
  },
  {
    _id: "5f2084fb56dc2428e9703ee5",
    category: ["5e5150bcc52a3904b74d6ff6", null],
    coordinates: { lat: 37.7787325, lng: -122.4572683 },
    location: { type: "Point", coordinates: [Array] },
    calcDistance: 3357.3418413767595,
  },
  {
    _id: "5f2084f856dc2428e96ff091",
    category: ["5e5150bcc52a3904b74d6ff6", null],
    coordinates: { lat: 37.8049528, lng: -122.4249378 },
    location: { type: "Point", coordinates: [Array] },
    calcDistance: 3377.281713590449,
  },
  {
    _id: "5f2084fb56dc2428e9703f73",
    category: ["5e5150bcc52a3904b74d6ff6", null],
    coordinates: { lat: 37.8049528, lng: -122.4249378 },
    location: { type: "Point", coordinates: [Array] },
    calcDistance: 3377.281713590449,
  },
  {
    _id: "5f2084fb56dc2428e9703f39",
    category: ["5e5150bcc52a3904b74d6ff6", null],
    coordinates: { lat: 37.7788351, lng: -122.4575644 },
    location: { type: "Point", coordinates: [Array] },
    calcDistance: 3384.6341862170793,
  },
  {
    _id: "5f14aa92745456119cf27701",
    category: ["5e5150f0c52a3904b74d6ffb", null],
    coordinates: { lat: 37.779187, lng: -122.4577491 },
    location: { type: "Point", coordinates: [Array] },
    calcDistance: 3405.9730381738473,
  },
  {
    _id: "5f2084fb56dc2428e9703f21",
    category: ["5e5150bcc52a3904b74d6ff6", null],
    coordinates: { lat: 37.8034776, lng: -122.4027084 },
    location: { type: "Point", coordinates: [Array] },
    calcDistance: 3501.3565554464535,
  },
];

const arrayToFilter = [
  "5e5150bcc52a3904b74d6ff6",
  "5e5150c6c52a3904b74d6ff7",
  "5e5150d6c52a3904b74d6ff8",
];

//initialize new array
const newArr = [];

arr.forEach((x) => {
  arrayToFilter.forEach((y) => {
    if (x.category[0] === y) {
      //push the item to the initialized
      //if the key of the item is matched
      newArr.push(x);
    }
  });
});

//you can use this also
//arr.forEach((x) =>
//  arrayToFilter.forEach((y) => x.category[0] === y && newArr.push(x))
//);

console.log(newArr);
```